# I see 2 root users (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

so I decided to view the list of users on my VPS and noticed that there are 2 root users. Me not being the smartest in terms of linux (That's why I bought a VPS, so I could learn), I assumed it was a backdoor of some sort, though I'd rather verify by you guys who do know if I should remove it or not. Here is an image: [image of the 2 root users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L67UP.png). If you guys could tell me if this is a backdoor or not that'd be great, thanks!

Comment: The title sounds like that famous line from the 6th sense.

Comment: Haha, quite the coincidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The left one is the user's *name*, the right one is the user's *group*. There are not two `root` users, it's just that the user `root` also belongs to the group `root`.

Here's a few links that talks about users and groups:

- [An Introduction to Linux Permissions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-linux-permissions)
- [Red Hat Deployment Guide - Chapter 3 - Managing Users and Groups](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Deployment_Guide/ch-Managing_Users_and_Groups.html)

Comment: Ah, thank you! I thought I was backdoored or soething for a second.